# css - Align text horizontally with edge of image

Tags: html, css

I want to align the text of a post horizontally with the right edge of a picture. i.e. In the picture below, I want the text to be on the right side of the black line, in line with the image. Kinda like twitter and facebook posts.

[image: horizontal-align]

How would I do this with just css?
Thanks

[EDIT]

Heres some HTML and CSS:

HTML:

```
<div class="post-container"><img class="avatar" src="/static/images/11_48.jpeg"><span class="post"> <b>Daniel</b> 
<p> asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd asdfasd </p> </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.avatar {
float: left;
margin-right:5px;
vertical-align:text-top;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-khtml-border-radius: 4px;  
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in two separate divs within a container, both floated left and having appropriate widths (left one should be the width of the image and the right one the width of the rest of the space) and heights (100%). There are many more ways to do this, but I think this one is the easiest and the most recommended.

Example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/2gTJ9/1/).

Comment: it doesn't work :( since divs are not inline, it just puts it under the image, and if I make them inline, then they look the same as before.

Comment: Yeah, must add the width since it's 100% by default. You're welcome and good luck! :)

Comment: I've created example 11 minutes ago, but who cares :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways to do this. You should just probably wrap both in in a  and then just move the text farther to the right by doing:

```
#text {
left: 100px; /* or however far you want it */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not need to separat image and paragraphe to 2 divs.
Do not need to change anything in the class avatar.
Adding the style below for p.
Then you will get what you want.

```
.text_align {
    padding-left: 20px; /* or ajust it with your needs */
    margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put `float: left;` on the image. Eg:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: the result of this answer will be exactly what the author of the quesiton dont wants to happen.

Comment: No idea how you can read their mind two years later. The question was also edited after this answer was posted, so it may no longer be relevant.